# Unicorn not happy with my rack version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mongoid, unicorn, digital-ocean

I have been repeating this tutorial for weeks now:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-1-click-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-with-digitalocean

Here are the specifics of my project:
I am using Mongoid with database.yml production set to my tested and working Droplet (DigitalOcean VPS) running MongoDB.

My gem file is here, I am new to Rails and am not quite sure if it's set up right, so I just moved them all to assets hoping Unicorn might serve these gems for me?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
  gem 'redcarpet', '1.17.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'


        gem "will_paginate_mongoid"
        gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
        gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

        gem 'devise'

        gem 'jquery-rails'



        gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"
end
```

Here's what I did:
I used DigitalOcean's 1 click installer. Then I used FileZilla to SFTP into the credentials they provided me with. I deleted all the files in /home/rails and put my new files in from my project. Then I executed bundle install, and restarted the unicorn service. In the tutorial I had seen I can track the log of unicorn, so I executed this: tail -f /home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log

Here is the output which concerns me:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.5. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I saw some other solutions to this, all failed. Here are the solutions I tried:
Deleting my Gemfile.lock, and re bundle installing it. Going into the file and removing where it said rack. Running bundle install --binstubs. Restarting the unicorn service with bundle exec before it. The error remains the same.

I've had many different errors before, but I feel this is the closest I have gotten. If someone could explain this to me (I'm new to Rails and would like a thorough explanation) and possibly help me fix the error that would be fantastic and end this frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess

```
gem "rack", "~> 1.4.5"
```

May work for you, then of course `bundle install` afterwards.

Comment: Hello, just tried this. The result is the same error. I tried changing it to the version the environment wants, 1.5.2, however the bundle is locked at 1.4.5. This is the result of trying to bundle update rack: rails (= 3.2.14) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.4.5) ruby

Comment: Installing with command line, and uninstalling the problematic version (1.5.2) worked!

Comment: @user2752843: man you are my life savio. **uninstalling the problematic version (1.5.2) worked!**

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem:

```
gem uninstall rack -v 1.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly reload your Ubuntu installation from the DigitalOcean control panel, then try and install Ruby on Rails with Apache and Passenger?

[Install RoR](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)

[Install Passenger (skip to passenger installation)](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger)

You will have errors when first creating your site with `rails new` as it will try and use SQL when it won't be installed, if you wish to use MongoDB